# Object turns purple after image texture used in Shading gets deleted

Tags: objects, shaders

Good Afternoon.

I dont know how well to organize the body of my question, so I'll write it out in bullets.

- I use blender from an external drive.
- I'm working on a project that requires me to use SHADING to add an image as texture for an Aloe Vera  Plant.
- The Plant Vase was also Crtl + C from a separate project.

[image]

- File location  for  both Image and Plant Vase is on Desktop (remember  Blender itself is used from an External Drive)
- Somehow, both image and plant vase have been deleted from desktop.
- Now Alove Vera Steam and  Plant Vase have turned purple. Most likely  because these files have been deleted from their original location (Desktop).[image]
  [image]

In case of future projects, I will have to Append objects from other projects, instead of Ctrl + C.  But for the image, what do I do so that the SHADING or Blender perharps, will retain it as a texture because it would have been the same story even if I had Blender on PC and the files on an external drive.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to make sure that you'll always have your images available, pack them so that they are part of the blend file: go into File > External Data > Pack Resources, or into the UV Editor or Image Editor, select the image and Image > Pack

Comment: @moonboots I just had his issue again. Do I tick the "Automatically Pack Resources" box?

Comment: Sure but don't forget that if the image is not used (prefix 0) it will be deleted even if the image is packed, if you want to avoid that make it Fake User

Comment: @moonboots. Hi! I want to add that I am unable to Automatically Pack Resources of .FBX files/models that I had imported. Is there something I can do about it? Or do I have to save the .fbx file as a .blend file first, then Append instead of importing it?